# C finding maximum number in a row of 2D array and replacing it with elements in the upper triangle

Tags: c, arrays, 2d

Basically i want to create a 2 dimensional array size NxN, find the maximum value in each row and replace it in the upper triangle or rather replace the elements with the maximum it for that specific row, but above the diagonal.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAXIMUM 100

int main()
{
     int n, i, j, temp,m;
    float a[MAXIMUM][MAXIMUM], max;
    printf("dimensions: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("input elements\n");
    for (i=0; i<n; i++){
        for (j=0; j<n; j++){
            scanf("%f",&a[i][j]);
        }
    }

    max=a[0][0];
    for (i=0; i<n; i++){
        for (j=0; j<n; j++)
            {
                if(max<a[i][j]){
                    max=a[i][j];
                }

            for(m=0;m<n;m++) //the problem starts here
                {
                    if(max>a[i][m]){
                        if(i+m>n-1){
                        a[i][m]=max;
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        }

            for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                printf("\n");
                    for(j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                            printf("%f ", a[i][j]);
                        }
        }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And what is your question ?

Comment: Any particular reason you're not determining the maximum values during the *load* loop-set rather than trying to do it afterward?

Comment: my question is, this thing it doesnt work properly i need some help, to point me to the right answer.
and i guess it would be because i need to change the maximum value for each row separately, so i need multiple max values

Answer (score 0):

J loop finishes every times, then m loop starts so the value of j is n-1 when it is in m loop.That is a problem.

Comment: yes i noticed it and have changed that part, but now if i input the array like so 
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9

its fine but if i completely reveres the input it doesnt calculate it properly, wether it upper or lower triangular

Answer (score 0):

maybe like this

```
for (i=0; i<n; i++){
    max=a[i][0];
    for (j=1; j<n; j++){
        if(max<a[i][j]){
            max=a[i][j];
        }
    }
    for(m=i;m<n;m++){
        a[i][m]=max;
    }
}
```